# highlight table row with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I know there are tons of posts on this, but I'm lost as to why mine doesn't work.

I'm trying to highlight a row in my table:

```
<tr class="videorow"><td>...</td>...</tr>
...
```

css:

```
.highlight {
   background-color: #a8cb17;
}
```

and finally my jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).on("click", ".videorow", function() {

    //highlight table
    jQuery(".highlight").removeClass("highlight");
    jQuery(this).addClass("highlight");
});
```

Basically I want to highlight a row and clear out when a new row is selected. This is the first part I can't even figure out.

In addition I want to highlight the entire row except I don't want the last column to trigger a highlight. In other words you can click the last column of the row but that won't change the highlight.

Something like:

```
jQuery(document).on("click", ".videorow", function() {

    //highlight table
    jQuery(".highlight").removeClass("highlight");
    jQuery('table tr td:not(:last-child)').addClass("highlight");
});
```

Any guidance on both of these issues is appreciated.

**EDIT**: typing too fast. Syntax errors are just me writing this out instead of copying...fixed now

Comment: try change css:`.highlight {
   background-color: #a8cb17;
}`
to:
`.highlight td{
   background-color: #a8cb17;
}`

Comment: Aside from the syntax errors (your second selector is not in a string) this looks fine.

Comment: What's the current behavior you are seeing?  Without providing a working copy, it's hard to tell what's going on.

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/RRK2M/1/

Comment: @AnhTú This is incorrect. He is only trying to apply this class on click. Not on default load

Comment: @CodyGuldner in the first load, there are 0 tr with class `highlight`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making sure your TD is inside your TR, for a start -- thought it may just be your question, not your code, in error.

```
<tr class="videorow">
<td>...</td>
</tr>
```

Then, try capturing the click event on the `<TD>` -- not on the `<TR>`. Many things work better on TD than on TR.

```
$('document').on( "click", "tr.videorow td", function(ev) {
   console.log('click videorow event', ev);
   // do whatever.
});
```

If you can't get it to work,  try just capturing on "td" until you can get the event-handler working & a log message appearing. (You're using Chrome or Firefox, I assume.)

Attaching the event-handlers to the table via an # ID selector, rather than the whole document, might also be more efficient.

```
$('#MyTable').on( ...);
```

Anh Tú's comment as to the CSS highlight, is also correct. Make it apply the background to the TD, not the TR. You can also try !important if you're still having trouble (though see http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/ for more info.)

```
.highlight td {background-color: #a8cb17 !important;}
```

Thanks Anh!  Hope this helps.

Comment: Hrmm, I'm lost. Tried your suggestions. click event does get triggered but for some reason no highlight...

Comment: Debug -- add something else (say a font-size) to your CSS, check in 'Inspect Element' if it's being applied, check the jQuery selector which is applying it.

Comment: Weird, adding font size changes the rows fonts as expected but still no highlighting...I'm ripping my hair out.

Comment: Maybe you've got more-specific CSS or a `style` attribute on the TD cells, which is higher-priority than the .highlight. Fix that, or try `!important` in your highlight CSS style.

Comment: +1 I hate CSS! You got it exactly. Thanks for sticking with me. What's with the down vote?

Answer (score 5):

```
jQuery(document).on("click", "tr.videorow > td", function() {
    var $this = jQuery(this);

    // ignore clicks on last column
    if ( $this.is(":last-child") ) return;

    // unhighlight currently selected row
    jQuery(".highlight").removeClass("highlight");

    // change the highlight of the row        
    $this.parent().addClass("highlight");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you wrote:

```
jQuery(table tr td:not(:last-child)).addClass("highlight");
```

It's has syntax error. The parameter passed to `jQuery` function is not `string`. Changed it to this one:

```
jQuery('table tr td:not(:last-child)').addClass("highlight");
```

Answer (score 0):

on row click use the following:

```
$('.row_selected').removeClass('row_selected');$(this).toggleClass('row_selected');
```