# how to highlight a table row when one of its cell is clicked using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table with multiple rows and columns on my web page.I need to highlight a table row when a user clicks on any of the row cells.

Just wondering if this is possible with jquery.

e.g. if user clicks on 80 the second row of the table needs highlighted.

I guess the issue is probably finding the row as we can add a class to that row easily to highlight it.

Any ideas?

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>80</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [highlight table row with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16410549/highlight-table-row-with-jquery)

Comment: Where is the js code you got so far? Finding the row is easy, something like `$(this).parent()` inside the click handler should do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with jQuery by adding a class to the parent `tr` of the clicked `td`:

```
$(function() {
    $('td').click(function() {
        $('tr').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active'); 
    });
});
```

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z23Lq3q3/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can :

```
$('td').on('click', function () {
  // Remove previous highlight class
  $('tr').removeClass('myAwesomeClass');

  // Get parent <tr> element
  var parent = $(this).parent();

  // Add a class to your parent row
  parent.addClass('myAwesomeClass');
});
```

Create a `css` to add styles to `.myAwesomeClass`, like background color.

Answer (score 1):

You want to add a highlight class to the clicked row, and remove it from all other rows, so something like....

```
$('table tbody').on('mousedown', 'tr', function(e) {
    $(this).addClass('highlight').siblings().removeClass('highlight');
})
```

and then in your css, have something along the lines of....

```
tbody > tr.highlight > td {
    background: #500;
}
```

The key is that you add the highlight class to the tr, but you actually apply the background highlight colour to the tds. The css shown will do this for you.

Here's a **[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/o4Okw0?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

You can do a click event on a table row if someone clicks any of the `<td>` in that row.

Like so:

`$('tr').on('click', function(){
    $('tr').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e2n6ppy1/2/)

Answer (score 0):

you can set the click handler to the 'tr'

```
$("table").on("click", "tr", function(){
    //remove class from any previous click
    $("table tr").removeClass("clicked");

    //add class to current row
    $(this).addClass("clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need more than one row highlighted at once :

JQuery:

```
$("td").on("click", function () {
    $(this).parent().addClass('highlight');
});
```

CSS:

```
.highlight {
    background-color: red;
}
```

If you need no more than one row highlighted at once :

JQuery:

```
$("td").on("click", function () {
    $("tr").each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('highlight');
    })
    $(this).parent().addClass('highlight');
});
```

CSS:

```
.highlight {
    background-color: red;
}
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/8bbc7vbu/